# Comment button functionality only appears on latest post and not all

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a post system for a social media site, and there is a comment button. However, when I click the comment button, it is meant to dropdown an input and only does it for one post, and not all. How can I make it display across all posts functionally?

````
          <hr class="">
            <div class="mb-3">
      <!-- Comment section goes here -->
      <style>
        .comment-form {
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .comment-form.active {
          max-height: 500px;
        }
      </style>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="comment-btn" data-post-id="<?php echo $row["post_id"]; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-comments" style="color: black;"></i>
      </a>

      <hr>
      <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comment-form" id="comment-form-<?php echo $row["post_id"]; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="comment_text" placeholder="Leave a comment here:" name="comment_text" rows="" style="margin-top: 10px;"></textarea>
          <?php if (isset($error) && !empty($error)): ?>
            <span class="text-danger">  <?php echo $error; ?></span>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button type="submit" class="post-comment-btn">Post Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $row["post_id"]; ?>">
      </form>
    </div>

  <script>
    const commentBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-btn');
    const commentForms = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-form');

    commentBtns.forEach((btn) => {
      const postId = btn.getAttribute('data-post-id');
      const form = document.querySelector(`#comment-form-${postId}`);

      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        form.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <?php
  $post_id = $row["post_id"];
  $sql_comments = "SELECT comments.*, users.username, users.profile_picture_url, users.verified, users.display_name FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.user_id WHERE comments.post_id = '$post_id' ORDER BY comments.created_date ASC";
  $result_comments = $conn->query($sql_comments);
  if ($result_comments->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row_comments = $result_comments->fetch_assoc()) {
      $comment_username = "@" . $row_comments["username"];
      $comment_verified = $row_comments["verified"];
      $comment_profile_picture_url = $row_comments["profile_picture_url"];
      $comment_display_name = $row_comments["display_name"];
      $comment_date = $row_comments["created_date"];
      $comment_text = $row_comments["comment_text"];
  ?>```
````

Comment: I think it would help us help you if you could put the actual HTML into your question.